# Is there a function to test if objects match other objects?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an object like this but more complex:

```
var obj = 
{
  a: foo,
  b: bar,
  sub:{
    a: foz
    }
}
```

and then I have a conditionals based on the keys and values, for example:

```
{
  a: ^f,
  sub:{
     a: z$
  }
}
```

Is there a method for checking the conditionals are true for all of the objects properties. I'm also fine with chome-only-features or something like underscore. I can also re-structure the structure of my conditionals.

Comment: No, there is no *built-in* method in browsers or underscore that does this.  You will have to loop over the object and do this yourself.  underscore can probably help you with the looping, but you will still have to do the comparison yourself.

Comment: Your "conditionals" doesn't have a test for `b`.  Would that mean it passes or fails?

Comment: You can use something like [chai](http://chaijs.com/api/assert/) *deepEqual* if you are testing .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can use deepEqual() or modify it to your needs

```js
var deepTest = function (x, y) {
  if ((typeof x == "object" && x != null) && (typeof y == "object" && y != null)) {
    if (Object.keys(x).length != Object.keys(y).length)
      return false;

    for (var prop in x) {
      if (y.hasOwnProperty(prop))
      {  
        if (! deepEqual(x[prop], y[prop]))
          return false;
      }
      else
        return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
  else if(x && (typeof y != "undefined")) return true; else return false;
}

document.write(deepEqual({a:{b:true}},{a:{c:1}}),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual({a:{b:true}},{a:{b:1}}),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual({a:{b:false}},{a:{c:1}}),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual({a:{b:false}},{a:{b:1}}),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual(true,true),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual(true,false),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual(false,false),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual(false,false),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual([true],[1]),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual([true],[]),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual([true],[]),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual([true,true],[]),'<br>');
document.write(deepEqual([true,true],[1,2]),'<br>');
```

Comment: Although, that's a nice start, it doesn't really solve the TO's problem, since he wants more complex "equals".

Comment: He's not looking for "equals" -- he's looking for pattern matching.

Comment: I feel that the statement if (x != y) should be rewritten as if(x && (typeof y != "undefined")) return true; else return false; ?

Comment: I modified the answer. Is this what is required?

Comment: @Barmar I used quotes to signal that.

Comment: Now it no longer compares equality of `x` and `y` as scalars. Would not downvote this, but wondering why it was accepted since it does not answer the question.

Comment: Could you write an example of test for the function? I added some other examples at the code, what is wrong?